# Golang HTTPS/TLS POST client/server

Tags: post, go, https

I have written a simple client/server in Go that will do an HTTP GET over TLS, but I'm trying to also make it capable of doing an HTTP POST over TLS.

In the example below `index.html` just contains the text `hello`, and the HTTP GET is working fine. I want the client to get the HTTP GET and write back, `hello world` to the server.

client

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    link := "https://10.0.0.1/static/index.html"

    tr := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    }
    client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
    response, err := client.Get(link)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    content, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    s := strings.TrimSpace(string(content))

    fmt.Println(s)

    // out := s + " world"      
    // Not working POST...
    // resp, err := client.Post(link, "text/plain", &out)

}
```

server

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/static/", func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Got connection!")
        http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "server.crt", "server.key", nil))
}
```

I also currently have nothing to handle the POST on the server side, but I just want it to print it out to the screen so when I run the client I will see the server print `hello world`.

How should I fix my client code to do a proper POST? And what should the corresponding server code look like to accept the POST? Any help would be appreciated, I'm having trouble finding HTTPS/TLS POST examples.

Comment: You need to add CA of your certificate to your transport [like](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38825553/2604529)

Comment: @MarcelNovy I'm using a self-signed certificate... That doesn't have anything to do with my question.

Comment: It would be useful if you mentioned how your current attempt at POST doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't share the error message, but I assume the `client.Post` call wasn't allowing a string as its third parameter, because it requires an `io.Reader`. Try this instead:

```
out := s + " world"     
resp, err := client.Post(link, "text/plain", bytes.NewBufferString(out))
```

On the server side, you already have the right code set up to handle the POST request. Just check the method:

```
http.HandleFunc("/static/", func (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        // handle POST requests
    } else {
        // handle all other requests
    }
})
```

I noticed one other issue. Using `index.html` probably won't work here. `http.ServeFile` will redirect that path. See https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile:

> As a special case, ServeFile redirects any request where r.URL.Path
>   ends in "/index.html" to the same path, without the final
>   "index.html". To avoid such redirects either modify the path or use
>   ServeContent.

I'd suggest just using a different file name to avoid that issue.