# How to do a https request with proxy

Tags: go, https, proxy

I am able to do a http or https client request without setting up a proxy,

```
enter code here
tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},     
}

client := &http.Client{}
client.Transport = tr

request, err := http.NewRequest("HEAD", "http://www.???.com", nil)
request.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36")

resp, err := client.Do(request)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
    return
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

httpcode = resp.Status
```

This script is working ok, I get a 200 ok when I request https url, but if I set up proxy , the script:

```
proxyString := "https://47.91.179.xxx:443"
proxyUrl, _ := url.Parse(proxyString)

tr := &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl),
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}, 
    
}

client := &http.Client{}
client.Transport = tr

....................
```

I always get "Bad request", I read docs: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/:

...........
Starting with Go 1.6, the http package has transparent support for the HTTP/2 protocol when using HTTPS. Programs that must disable HTTP/2 can do so by setting Transport.TLSNextProto (for clients) or Server.TLSNextProto (for servers) to a non-nil, empty map. Alternatively, the following GODEBUG environment variables are currently supported:
..............

So, I tried to stop http2:

```
tr := &http.Transport{
    Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl),
    //Proxy: http.ProxyFromEnvironment,
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
    TLSNextProto:    make(map[string]func(authority string, c *tls.Conn) http.RoundTripper),
}
```

same problem, "Bad request". I tried os.Setenv("HTTPS_PROXY", "47.91.???.???:443"), It is the same result.
This is logged in server:

```
{S;}220.255.95.68{S;}-{S;}07/Mar/2017:17:01:47 +0800{S;}CONNECT www.panpacific.com:443 HTTP/1.1{S;}400{S;}173{S;}340{S;}-{S;}-{S;}-{S;}-{S;}-{S;}www.panpacific.com
```

So, Does golang support https client request via proxy? How do I get correct results?

Comment: I tested your code against my proxy server and it worked fine. It may be a configuration problem with your proxy. Have you tried using an ordinary web browser with this proxy?

Comment: hi,IanB 
what is your proxy server? I use nginx (Reverse proxy). 
Do you use  [TLSNextProto] to stop http2?

Comment: I use Squid proxy. No, I do not specify TLSNextProto. A reverse proxy should not require the client to use *any* special proxy configuration i.e. it should be transparent

Comment: Dup of the title: [How to program Go to use a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845690/how-to-program-go-to-use-a-proxy), but not the same problem.

Comment: I am quite certain that the problem is with the proxy URL. Specifically, proxies must be accessed using HTTP protocol, and you specify HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your `Client.Transport.Proxy` configuration.  Both attempted approaches ([`ProxyURL`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ProxyURL) and [`ProxyFromEnvironment`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ProxyFromEnvironment)) should work fine to specify a [forward proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Proxy_server&oldid=913996143#Types_of_proxy_servers).

Relevant question: [How to program Go to use a proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51845690/86967)

Something to look out for, however unlikely, is that subsequent client-side calls to not somehow bypass the use of [WriteProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.WriteProxy) and instead call [Write](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Write) directly -- since this would defeat the proxy specification.

---

Given the information provided here, "Bad Request" likely indicates that you are reaching the proxy, but that it is not working correctly as a generic HTTP/HTTPS forward proxy, which is what `Client.Transport.Proxy` would specify.

Maybe some clarity would be added here: [How to use Nginx as a HTTP/HTTPS proxy server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/298392/how-to-use-nginx-as-a-http-https-proxy-server).  In summary, NGINX is not normally used as a forward proxy, so maybe this isn't what you are trying to do.

*If you are trying to use NGINX as a reverse proxy, then configuration is a server-side concern and your clients do not need special proxy configuration -- just change your request URL to point to the proxy.*

---

Side note: If not otherwise specified, `&http.Client{}` will use [`DefaultTransport`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#RoundTripper) which automatically includes `ProxyFromEnvironment`, so the extra proxy configuration is only required if you are constructing a non-default Transport (as is done in the question in order to specify [`InsecureSkipVerify`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38822764/86967)) or you want to have an application-specific proxy confuration.  *And, to repeat, client-side proxy configuration is only needed when using a forward proxy.*

Comment: Forward HTTP proxy: [How exactly does a proxy work?](https://superuser.com/a/1262330/114579)