# Get https://<mydomain.com>/translate/2327496366232: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: http, go, https

In my Go App, I make a call to `Hostname+"/translate/12345`

Thing is depending the environment, in local `Hostname` will be on http, and in production, it will be on `https`

When I test the production route on https with postman, there is no problem, route works fine.

But when I run it from WS, I get:

```
Get https://<mydomain.com>/translate/2327496366232: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
```

Here is my code:

```
var terID string
client := http.Client{}
req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", Hostname+"/translate/"+terID, nil)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
req.SetBasicAuth(Username, Password)
res, err := client.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
```

What can I do to fix that ?

Comment: close to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122159/how-to-do-a-https-request-with-bad-certificate / https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47464161/golang-http-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira/issues/52, please try

```
import ("net/http"; "crypto/tls")

tr := &http.Transport{
    TLSClientConfig: &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify : true},
}
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}
```